# How to read the current directory when opening Python interpreter in .pythonstartup file set in PYTHONSTARTUP?

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm setting up `.pythonstartup` (or whatever called) by defining it as an environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP`. 
 What I try to do is read the path to current directory when opening Python interpreter (or when hitting the `User$ Python`command), but not the one where `PYTHONSTARTUP` is in (this is usually **Home directory**). I'd like to read different Python setup files by directories (such as `.pythonrc`), but not all the same settings with `.pythonstartup`.
However the issue is when using python module `os.getwd()` it reads where `.pythonstartup` is in, of course. Are there any way to achieve this? Thanks a lot for your help.